# Display a custom column from a blog list in a summary view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, blog, view

1. I have created a blog using sharepoint 2010
2. I added a few new column using sharepoint designer
3. List-post-add new column.
4. Of couse each post I edit and added the content to the extra field.

However I can't view the output or any content from the newly added column on my main homepage.. Which is summary view I guess.

Can anyone guide me on how I can add these to my summary view? And I can't seem to see anywhere I can edit the summary view even when I am using sharepoint designer...

---

**Edit in response to @sbc111's answer:**
The problem is there is no such thing as modify for Summary View. so what i did yesterday is hard code the script like that..

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Fields">            
            <xsl:if test="@Name ='Permalink' or @Name ='Banner'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]!=''">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink">
                            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

"Banner" is the column I created. Can anyone guide me what that means?

Comment: I think you need to customize column that included in default view of the list, look for button on the ribbon

Comment: is there a tutorial or guide on how to do that?

Comment: you can find Modify view button in List tab when you viewing content of the list

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify views (or create new ones) to include your new column(s) - it is straightforward and this post shows how it can be done: [Create, modify, or delete a view.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-modify-or-delete-a-view-HA010377693.aspx)